# How to convert tuple fields into individual tuples in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a tuple in pig which has the below value

```
a= (abcd|def|xyz, pqrs|uvw|xyz, ..... )
```

The number of fields varies, but the | delimited fields does not change. I want to convert this to a data structure like below

```
((abcd, def,xyz),(pqrs,uvw,xyz),.......)
```

So that I can process the data further. My below code is not working

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE STRSPLIT(a.$0,'|');
```

This only creates a one tuple

```
((abcd,def,xyz))
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: post the entire script, most likely you have loaded the data into more than 1 field and hence when you split a.$0 you are seeing only the first tuple

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Actually I found that I had to convert the individual records to its own tuple by using a TOBAG . It works now..Thanks for the help